# Is a coin toss pseudo-random or truly random?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time-evolution, chaos-theory, determinism, randomness

I wonder if a coin toss is pseudo-random or truly random. Sure, you could say that a coin toss is pseudo-random because you don't know the speed of the coin or its rotation, but if you were to include all these factors in a calculation, the result should be predictable. I am not sure, however, to what extent chaos in the air through which one tosses the coin contributes to the result. Since such chaos is caused by true randomness, surely the result of a coin toss should also be truly random. Is my consideration correct and is a coin toss pseudo-random or truly random?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Since such chaos is caused by true randomness, surely the result of a coin toss should also be truly random.* - Why do you think that 'such chaos' is caused by 'true randomness'? In classical mechanics, if you know the initial conditions of all particles and how they interact, you can predict the future in a completely deterministic way. Roughly speaking, [deterministic chaos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory) means that for some systems, a small change in the initial conditions leads to a large change (i.e. completely different behavior) in the future.

Comment: @JasonFunderberker I think what you say applies to systems with few degrees of freedom. For a system with $N_A\sim 10^{23}$ particles knowing the initial conditions *and/or* predicting future may be impossible for computational reasons, which are potentially unsurmountable.

Comment: @RogerVadim Yes, I of course meant *in principle*...

Comment: @JasonFunderberker I mean Heisenberg's uncertainty principle, according to which, for example, the position of many particles (even in the air) is uncertain. If one takes the Copenhagen interpretation of the quantum mechanics, then this position is determined finally by true randomness.

Comment: You might find this interesting https://youtu.be/nJObMJLweCs

Comment: With practice and skill, it is possible to toss a coin and then catch it in such a manner as to always get tails or heads as desired.  there is a famous physicist who can perform this trick on demand. If I remember his name I'll include it here.